# how can I create a new project without appcompat_v7

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I am unable to get why appcompat_v7 is created automatically... finding it very irritating..  please someone help to get rid off this problem.
I tried to create new project and found like this for every newly created project.

Comment: http://axgig.com/images/55071455052979484297.png like this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why eclipse automatically adds appcompat v7 library support whenever i create a new project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261288/why-eclipse-automatically-adds-appcompat-v7-library-support-whenever-i-create-a)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When creating new Android Project, remove the check in front of "Create activity". By doing this, Eclipse will not automatically import the library project "appcompat_v7".
Then you manually have to create main activity. Be careful what imports you use if you have stuff like `Fragment` or `ActionBar`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261288/why-eclipse-automatically-adds-appcompat-v7-library-support-whenever-i-create-a) is very useful.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

When you create your application, give API 14:Android 4.0 or an upper version as the minimum SDK version.

Answer (score 1):

the reason why Eclipse does this is because there is a lot of fragmentation in different vendors and versions of android and the same reflects in the API's too..!! So in order keep everything going smooth Android suggests adding external libraries to the project and Eclipse abides to the same.

You can get rid of it if you have built, target and compile level as same, using minimum SDK above 7 shall also do the trick.

refer
[Why does Eclipse automatically add appcompat v7 library support whenever I create a new project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261288/why-eclipse-automatically-adds-appcompat-v7-library-support-whenever-i-create-a)