# searching button showing menu bar not seen action bar

Tags: android

[image]
[image]

I try to design action bar. When i create new android project, Appcompat imported directly. I found this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261288/why-eclipse-automatically-adds-appcompat-v7-library-support-whenever-i-create-a),

I think this is due to library. it is showing on menu bar but I want to use action bar which has writing actionBarDemo(near actionBarDemo writing). How can I solve this problem ?
How can I change it ? What is problem ?

**this is my main.class**

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionmenu, menu);

        return true;
    }

  }
```

**this Xml of menu bar:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.bbb.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <!-- Search / will display always -->
    <item android:id="@+id/derya"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:icon="@drawable/indoor"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>

    <!-- Location Found -->
    <item android:id="@+id/duygu"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:icon="@drawable/refresh"
          android:title="@string/action_location_found"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```