# How to remove appcompat v7 library in android

Tags: android

when i create new project in android it automatically add appcompat v7 library but i want remove this library.

So How to Remove appcompat library?

Thank You.

Comment: why do you want to remove that..your app will support all the devices if you keep this.
follow the answers provided here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261288/why-eclipse-automatically-adds-appcompat-v7-library-support-whenever-i-create-a

Comment: but i want to use sherlock library and when i use appcompat library with sherlock library it generate error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the appcompat library.  right click select delete well actually just close the appcompat project.  You'll have to clean up a few things in the v11 v7 styles folders.  That's about it.  Unless your using something that's actually in the appcompat library for instance the supportactionbar in which case you can't remove the appcompat library.