# What is appcompat_v7 features , functions and how can i remove this without affect to my project

Tags: android, ide, adt, android-appcompat

what is the functions and features, of appcompat_v7? in latest version adt.
or can i remove and can i run normally  android project.

[image: Appcomcat V_7 Folder library][image: android.support.v7.appcompat jar file]

Comment: What did Google tell you? What research have you done already?

Comment: Check this So [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22261555/2811956) this One Surely Helps You

Comment: how should i do, i remove this jar file and dependency from my project, the error reach at <b>styles.xml<b>

Answer (score 0):

It adds support for Action bar UI. Dependency for this library is V4 support library. If you are not using any components from this library then you remove it.