# “appcompat_v7” project is contains error

Tags: android, eclipse

After creating a new android project, Eclipse automatically creates a "appcompat_v7" project without any files under /src. But it shows error in styles.xml on the following line, which is line 18 in the styles.xml.

**style name="Widget.MediaRouter.MediaRouteButton"
            parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"**

I have no idea how or why Eclipse is creating this project.

I am new to Android developing. please help me to solve this error.

Comment: `also getting a weird error` which you don't tell us. Well played... Please read the [FAQ] about how to create good questions. Especially this part: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Eclipse is creating this project because your new project is using ActionBar which which relies on this project.

Comment: try to install sdk-21 library and set 21 in project properties file

Comment: look appcompact_v7 is support library not project.

Comment: Make a good habit of google the things first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261288/why-eclipse-automatically-adds-appcompat-v7-library-support-whenever-i-create-a

Comment: Its a bug in that version, delete your workspace and create a new one

Comment: @Arunkumar G Welcome to `StackoverfLow` ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to style.xml and inside resources put

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

    -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

</style>
```