# open new Project error : Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a big trouble on Eclipse

I download the latest ADT bundle, then new a new Android project but an error occurred :

[image]

then i google it and found some suggestions, such as new workspace, but still not work

[image]

and i found a strange phenomenon, java compiler always changed to 1.4, and jre always missing, it occurred every time when the workspace changed

[image]

[image]

the new project is weird too

[image]

i choose property of the project, another error occurred when selected Android

[image]

Then i google the error, found a solution is create a file named default.properties, put it in the root of project, and it worked, but i still can not create layout file or editing string.xml file

[image]
[image]

What's wrong with my Eclipse?

Comment: Try to prefer android studio instead of Eclipse.

Comment: ... no i have a lot of project in eclipse

Comment: Have you update build tools from Android SDK Manager ?

Comment: Yes, i update it after download ADT bundle

Comment: before update your eclipse is working or not ?

Comment: no, the same situation with the description above = =

Answer (score 2):

Adding following line in eclipse.ini worked for me

```
-vm
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Commands/java
```

Comment: adding those two lines before the -vmargs line is the only way it worked for me

Comment: It didn't work for me. I am using Eclipse Luna which desperately requires  java 1.7 to start.

Answer (score 1):

ADT bundle does not work with the Oracle Java 7 SE JDK, failing with an NPE in the Android Application Project wizard.

Here's a workaround that lets you keep Java 7 as the default but run ADT with Java 6 when you have both installed. Bring up $ADT_DIR/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini in an editor.  Before the -vmargs line, insert these two lines:

```html
-vm
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Commands/java
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this issue for a while, it was a combination of answers that solved it for me:

1. Needed to update eclipse.ini as mentioned above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26207435/2162226

   -vm
       /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home
       -vmargs
2. In AndroidManifest.xml set minSdk='14'
   As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22564119/2162226
   When creating a new project "the folder appcompat_v7 doesnt get created" with minSdk=14